# Sharing columns or rows in a grid

Tags: wpf, grid

I'm trying to create an asymmetrical layout using a `Grid` where i have 2 rows, 2 columns and an extra shared column as follows:

```
<Grid Background="Black">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="200" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="200" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Rectangle
        Grid.Row="0"
        Grid.Column="0"
        Width="200"
        Height="200"
        Fill="Red" />
    <Rectangle
        Grid.Row="0"
        Grid.Column="1"
        Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
        Width="250"
        Height="200"
        Fill="Blue" />
    <Rectangle
        Grid.Row="1"
        Grid.Column="0"
        Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
        Width="250"
        Height="200"
        Fill="Yellow" />
    <Rectangle
        Grid.Row="1"
        Grid.Column="2"
        Width="200"
        Height="200"
        Fill="Green" />
</Grid>
```

But however i try to set it up, the second column always collapses unless i explicitly set a fixed width (in this case 50px). Why is this happening?

Shouldn't the second column resize itself to the remainder of each rectangle?

Comment: Did you try setting column zero and two width to auto, and column 1 width to *?

Comment: But that would mean that if i don't set the size of the last `rectangle` it will collapse. Sorry, i didn't explain enough. My goal is basically to have 4 different views, 3 of them collapsed and the last expanded. Thus, using `*` to fill the window.

Comment: For now, I did manage to achieve what i wanted using a converter to calculate the shared column size, but i would like a way that doesn't involves a converter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a `Converter` i managed to manually calculate the shared column size by placing the content of the first column in a container and binding the width of the shared column to the ActualWidth of that container subtracted by the first column width.

e.g.

```
<Grid Background="Black">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="200" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="200" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding ElementName=Rect3, Path=ActualWidth, Converter={StaticResource SharedColumnConverter}, ConverterParameter=200}" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Rectangle
        Grid.Row="0"
        Grid.Column="0"
        Width="200"
        Height="200"
        Fill="Red" />
    <Rectangle
        Grid.Row="0"
        Grid.Column="1"
        Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
        Width="250"
        Height="200"
        Fill="Blue" />
    <Rectangle
        Name="Rect3"
        Grid.Row="1"
        Grid.Column="0"
        Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
        Width="250"
        Height="200"
        Fill="Yellow" />
    <Rectangle
        Grid.Row="1"
        Grid.Column="2"
        Width="200"
        Height="200"
        Fill="Green" />
</Grid>
```